# RVM on production server?

Tags: ruby, rvm, production-environment

Can we use RVM in a production server?

I heard that we can't use RVM on a production server, but I do not get the reason for why not.

Can anyone tell me why we can't use RVM on production server?

Comment: Why not? If production server is dedicated you can use it.

Comment: so we can install and use multiple versions of ruby on production server right ?

Comment: Yes, I don't see any problem.

Comment: but if my production server has many applications running on it then how can we manage ruby version for each application ?

Comment: It's another question. ;) Maybe phusion passenger, eh?

Comment: are you sure  about phusion passenger ?

Comment: Why do not try and then ask more specific questions?

Comment: i wll try out definitely..

Comment: Read the RVM docs. It can be used in multi-user systems. It was not originally intended for it, but has been shown to work. The Install page talks about how to do it. If you only need one version of Ruby on the machine then don't complicate matters with RVM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to manage multiple projects with multiple Ruby versions in your server, it is better you use RVM in production. (But, of course it won't happen too often).

If you require only one Ruby version exclusively for production server, you should not get into a mess by keeping RVM with different versions of Ruby in production mode.

Comment: yes, i agree with you but suppose we have 2 different applications and one requires ruby 1.9.x and second one requires 2.x then how it can be managed by RVM ?

Comment: Then you use RVM. Install RVM using command 'rvm get stable'. Then Just see the rubies by running command 'rvm list known'. Then install each ruby version by running 'rvm install ruby-version'. for using a particular version use command 'rvm use ruby-version'. Thats all. You are done.

Comment: Some people do not like having gcc, g++, make and more dev tools on their production servers.